# Taking variable from div to use as the map style - not working?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On my site I have some divs which contain content that I turn into variables which are used in my map options.This method works fine for longitude and latitude however it doesn't work with the "styles".

When I console.log the output of the map_style variable and replace the variable in the mapOptions the style shows fine. However when using the code below I get no errors and the style doesn't show.

```
<div id="map-style">[{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"lightness":100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#C6E2FF"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#C5E3BF"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#D1D1B8"}]}]</div>
<div id="long">174.78840219999995</div>
<div id="lat">-36.8603516</div>

//Code in the javascript map function
var long = Number(document.getElementById('long').innerHTML);
var lat = Number(document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML);
var map_style = document.getElementById('map-style').innerHTML;

var mapOptions = {
  styles: map_style,
  center: {lat: lat, lng: long},
  zoom: 15,
};
```

Comment: you could try `var map_style = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('map-style').innerHTML);`

Comment: Thanks mate this worked aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var map_style = document.getElementById('map-style').innerHTML;
```

`map_style` is a string.  It needs to be a javascript object.

from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapOptions):

```
styles  
Type:  Array
Styles to apply to each of the default map types. Note that for Satellite/Hybrid and Terrain modes, these styles will only apply to labels and geometry.
```

Call JSON.parse on the string.

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  //Code in the javascript map function
  var long = Number(document.getElementById('long').innerHTML);
  var lat = Number(document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML);
  var map_style = document.getElementById('map-style').innerHTML;

  var mapOptions = {
    styles: JSON.parse(map_style),
    center: {
      lat: lat,
      lng: long
    },
    zoom: 15,
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map-style">[{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"lightness":100},{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#C6E2FF"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#C5E3BF"}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#D1D1B8"}]}]</div>
<div id="long">174.78840219999995</div>
<div id="lat">-36.8603516</div>

<div id="map_canvas" style="width:750px; height:450px; border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
```